# Android: ids in items in a listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview, each item has 2 checkboxes, I want one of these to be checked automatically if the other is checked (that is in the same item). But the result I have is that when I check the second checkbox in any item, it is the first checkbox of the first item that is checked! (and not in the same item)

The code of checkboxes in xml:
`

```
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CheckBox" 
                android:onClick="handler"
            />`
```

The code of the function handler:

`

```
public void handler(View v) {

     CheckBox rb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);

     rb.setChecked(true);
```

}
`

Does anyone know how to solve it and indicate that the checkbox to check is the one in the same item (it has the same id no?) ?

Comment: don't use onClick, but rather add a OnCheckedChangeListener

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you really don't need the `handler()` method at all. A CheckBox's default behavior is to check when it is clicked, without you calling `setChecked()`. `setChecked()` is typically used when you want to explicitly check or uncheck a CheckBox outside of the standard click-to-check/uncheck flow.

However, if you really want the handler method to work (and assuming all of your CheckBoxes call `hanlder()` on click), you may find you have better luck using the View that is passed to the function as so:

```
public void handler(View v) {
    CheckBox rb = (CheckBox) v;
    rb.setChecked(true);
}
```

Comment: What I mean is that on click, apart of the fact that  the clicked checkbox gets checked, the other checkbox is checked too. (if the first one is checked the other gets checked automatically)

Comment: Well you are always setting `checkBox3` to checked, so if the first checkbox is *not* `checkBox3`, that's your problem.

Comment: Its id is checkBox3 in all items (in all lines of the list) no? The problem is how can I indicate that it is the one in the same item as the checkbox clicked

Comment: See my suggested changes to your `handler()` function. If you don't utilize the View passed in through the click event, you aren't going to have much luck finding the correct `checkBox3`.